# How to change dynamically the name of a variable in an interface when creating the object?

Tags: typescript, object, properties

I'm trying to build an little 2D map editor. My basic map slot is an class with x and y properties. When building the map, a function creates all maps slots according to the requested map size and assigns the X/Y coordinates.

I want to add some custom parameters (from external source) in the basic Map slot class. The parameters names comes from an array.

I tried to create new parameters using an interface that I clone with a function and before creating map, I merge the basic smap slot object with the custom parameters  .. that doesn't seems to work and I think I'm on the wrong way.

Parameters are created as expected but they get same name so later when i want to merge new parameters with main MapClass I only got 1 exemple of custom string parameter and 1 custom number parameter. (constructor works well, but every custom variable has the same name .. at the end, there is only 2 variables)

In the createAdditionalNumberParameter() function, the "newParameterName" provided as argument can't be used as variable name in the newCustomParameter object.. and I don't know how to do differently ..

Anyone has an advice ? I'm beginner, maybe I choose the wrong way to proceed..

```
var additionalStringParametersList = ["stringParam1", "stringParam2"];
var additionalNumberParametersList = ["numberParam1", "numberParam2"];



const mapLength = 21;
const numberOfSlots = mapLength * mapLength;


var slotDatas = [];
var slotIDs = [];

var additionalStringParameters = [];
var additionalNumberParameters = [];
var additionalParametersCounter: number = 0;
var customParameter: Record<string, string>;

interface customParameter<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

function createAdditionalNumberParameter(newParameterName: string) {
    additionalParametersCounter++;
    let newCustomParameter: customParameter<number> = {
        newParameterName: 0
    };
        
    let key: keyof customParameter<number> = newParameterName;
    let value: customParameter<number>[typeof newParameterName] = newCustomParameter[key];

    additionalNumberParameters.push(newCustomParameter);
    console.log(newParameterName);
}

function createAdditionalStringParameter() {
    additionalParametersCounter++;
    let newCustomParameter: customParameter<string> = {
        newParam: "default"
    };
        
    let key: keyof customParameter<string> = 'newParam';
    let value: customParameter<string>['newParam'] = newCustomParameter[key];

    additionalStringParameters.push(newCustomParameter);
}

function createAdditionalParameters() {
    let i1 = 0;
    let i2 = 0;

    while(i1 < additionalStringParametersList.length) {
        i1++;
        createAdditionalStringParameter();
    }

    while(i2 < additionalNumberParametersList.length) {
        let parameterName: string = additionalNumberParametersList[i2];
        i2++;
        createAdditionalNumberParameter(parameterName);
    }
}

class MapSlotData {
    x: bigint;
    y: bigint;
    playable: boolean;

    constructor(x, y, playable) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.playable = playable;

        // Assign Custom Parameters 

        let i1 = 0;
        let i2 = 0;
    
        while(i1 < additionalNumberParameters.length) {
            Object.assign(this, additionalNumberParameters[i1]);
            i1++;
        }
        while(i2 < additionalStringParameters.length) {
            Object.assign(this, additionalStringParameters[i2]);
            i2++;
        }
        /*
        console.log(additionalNumberParameters.length)        
        console.log(additionalStringParameters.length)
        */
    } 
}


function createSlots()  {
    // creates slots ID
    let i = 0;

    while(i < numberOfSlots) {
        slotIDs.push(i);
        i++;
    }

    return slotDatas;

}

function setPlayablesSlots() {
    
    let i = 0;
    let i2 = 0;
    let iMax = slotIDs.length;
    let entier; 

    while(i < iMax) {
        let x = 1;
        let y = i;
        let playable = false;

        entier = i / mapLength ;
        i2 = Math.floor(entier);
        x = i2 + 1;
        if(x == 1 || x == 11 || x == 21) {
            playable = true;
        }
        if(y == 1 || y == 11 || y == 21) {
            playable = true;
        }
        y = i + 1 - i2 * mapLength;
        let MapSlotDataData = new MapSlotData(x, y, playable);
        slotDatas[i] = MapSlotDataData;
        i++;
    }
    console.log(slotDatas)
    return slotDatas;
}

createAdditionalParameters();
createSlots();
setPlayablesSlots();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WzLp4N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I've edited the post with the full code.

The idea to make it as simple as possible is to feed the MapSlotData class with properties from an external source (symbolized for the moment by the two arrays), set a default value and if possible a type.

I am open to any comment even if it does not concern the main problem... I would like to understand what is the right way to approach this situation